# How to remove menu header in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have menu header in my php that I'd like to remove.How?

PHP:

```
if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) {
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"></span>&nbsp;';
        } else {
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        }

        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ( $args->has_children ) ? ' </a><span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }// End if().
}
```

HTML Output:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact </a><span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

The header menu item is `contact` along with `fa-angle-down`

Or could this be achieved with CSS? Tried`.fa-angle-down {display: none;}`and`.menu-item-3530 {display:none;}` but it doesn't do what I want-namely getting menu to go from bars to menu whilst not displaying `contact` header item.

Please see here for full navwalker.php https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/shapely/blob/master/inc/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php

And here for my header.php https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/shapely/blob/master/header.php

Please see page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

This seems to be an issue not just with Shapely Theme, but that WordPress puts header menu item by default.

Does it have anything to do with `aria-hidden?`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute

Comment: please write the code properly so that everyone can understand your problem, you have missed closing braces on your php code and closing tags on your html

Answer (score 0):

It's your theme. It's set up to show a hamburger icon for the menu for all screen sizes.

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
```

This statement makes it true for a desktop. And on top of that, the icon is defined as a child of a flex item, which means you can't just set display: none. that doesn't work with flex.

I did get rid of the icon by overriding flex with inline: block, then setting display: none on the icon, but the menu still doesn't show up.

My recommendation: change themes.